# Finding Asymptotic Variance

Tags: statistics

Can anyone help walk me through finding the asymptotic variance for some random variable?

For example, let us consider $\sqrt{n}(\bar{y}-\mu) \equiv *$

I think this converges in distribution to ~N(O,V)

but I am unsure what 'V' is.

I assume: $y_i=1,2,...,n$ an i.i.d sequence, $E(y_i)=\mu$, $Var(y_i)=\sigma^2$ and $\bar{y}$ takes the standard definition (from the analogous principle).

My attempt at Avar(*):

$* \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i - \mu$ which converges in distribution to N(0,V)

Since the asymptotic variance of a random variable is the variance of the asymptotic distribution of a random variable, I can take Avar to be the variance generally associated with a normally distributed variable.

That is, $E(y^2)-E(y)^2$     (correct?)

Then I substitute * for y and have:

$$E(*^2)-E(*)^2 \equiv \frac{1}{n}Var(\sum y_i) \equiv \frac{1}{n} n\sigma^2 = \sigma^2=Avar(\sqrt{n}(\bar{y}-\mu)$$

where I use: $Var(ax+b)=a^2Var(x)$

Summary of my questions:

1. Is this correct? 
   1a. If not - can you please help me fix it?
2. Can anyone talk about how this is equivalent to/ an application of the delta method
3. Can anyone provide a good explanation (possibly including a detailed example) of how to apply the delta method in a situation where things are not so well behaved?

I am using Woolridge's graduate text to try and learn this concept but am not really getting it.

Thanks very much!